# How to convert offset as a static string to a const int C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, offset

So i have a function that scans a signature from a program and adds it to a string, i was wondering how i could add that string and turn it to a const int to use it in other functions

```
public static string RoundSkipOffset = "0x69B73F7";
```

and i want to get it in the format of

`public const int RoundSkipOffset = 0x69B73F7;`

ive tried parse but couldnt find a way, sorry if this is stupid i am very new to coding

Comment: Are you suggesting that you want to set a constant at run time? Or are you just saying that you want those hex digits as a number instead of a string? If the former, you can't. If the latter, just type in the digits without the spaces. If you're saying something else, i don't know what it is.

Comment: i was implying that i convert the empty string into an int, the hex digits are used to turn the empty box into an offset (ie: 0x69B73F7) when the program is run and that is what i would like to convert to an int

Comment: A assume with "_scans a signature from a program_" you mean to say you are scanning a file. Since a file is made of bytes (any file that has a file size >0, really), there should be no need to utilize strings for this. Just read the 4 bytes making up the offset from the file and combine them into an `int` or `uint`. If the offset in question is stored in LSB order in the file, you can make reading the offset value from the file even easier by utilizing `BinaryReader`'s `ReadInt32` or `ReadUInt32` method.

Comment: Also note that `int` is a signed data type. That means, if there is the slightest chance that the offset could be larger than 0x7FFFFFF, you shouldnt' use an `int`. (i.e., offset values of 0x80000000 or larger cannot be represented as is by the `int` data type. You can combine the four bytes of such large values into an `int`, but the resulting int value would be negative. You probably don't want your offset turn into some unrelated negative integer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the sequence is *too long* for `int` (which has `4` bytes only), `long` (which consist of `8` bytes); you can use `BigInteger` since you want `10` bytes to store:

```
using System.Numerics;

...

string RoundSkipSig = "8B 91 20 02 00 00 8B CA 83 E1";

...

readonly BigInteger result = BigInteger
  .Parse(RoundSkipSig.Replace(" ", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Note, that

1. You should get rid of spaces before before parsing
2. You can't declare `result` as `const` since you compute it in *runtime*

**Edit:** if you have *small* value which fit `int` range you can `Convert`

```
public static readonly int RoundSkipOffset = Convert.ToInt32("0x69B73F7", 16);
```

again, you can't use `const` but `readonly`